# Como fazer este ícone com CSS puro?

Tags: css, icons

É possível fazer com CSS o ícone da imagem abaixo?

[image: Page Icon]

Se sim, como posso fazer?

Testei fazer assim, porém não consigo criar a terceira página, só consigo fazer duas:

```css
.pages:before{
  content: "";
  width:25px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#FF0004; /*vermelho*/
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.pages{
  width:25px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#F8FF00;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  top:4px;
  left:4px;
}
.pages:after{
  content: "";
  width:25px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#2200FF; /*azul*/
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
}
```

```html
<span class="pages"></span>
```

Sei que eu poderia criar 3 spans diferentes uma pra cada página e aplicar um estilo para cada uma, mas não acredito ser viável criar elementos HTML em exceço.

Comment: Você acha que vale a pena o esforço de criar icons com CSS?

Comment: O esforço vai valer não só pelo site, mas pela experiência de aprender tal, já que é um lado interessante do CSS para explorar.

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-beautiful-icon-with-css3--net-21915

Comment: rapaz, use svg...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Que tal assim?

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
}

#first {
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#second {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#third {
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div id="first" class="block"></div>
  <div id="second" class="block"></div>
  <div id="third" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o exemplo do Leon Freire, pode remover os IDs dos elementos e trocar as regras no CSS pra agir nas classes

```
.block:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```